# XSL template for converting XML to JSON

Tags: json, xml, xslt

I used saxon v9 to profile an XSL transformation which converts XML to JSON. The profiler tells me that the function which escapes certain characters takes about 70% of the total processing time. The conversion is important because otherwise the created JSON file will be invalid because of characters that break the strings.

```
java -jar saxon9he.jar -xsl:jsontransform.xslt -s:input.xml -o:output.json -TP
```

The "method" used to escape the values looks like this:

```
<xsl:template name="escapejson">
        <xsl:param name="string"/>
        <xsl:sequence select="replace(
                              replace(
                              replace(
                              replace(
                              replace( 
                              replace(
                              replace(
                              replace(
                              replace($string, '\\','\\\\'), 
                              '/', '\\/'),
                              '&quot;', '\\&quot;'),
                              '&#xA;','\\n'),
                              '&#xD;','\\r'),      
                              '&#x9;','\\t'),  
                              '\n','\\n'),
                              '\r','\\r'),
                              '\t','\\t')"/>
    </xsl:template>
```

Unfortunately, my XSL knowledge is too limited to create an optimum solution on my own. I assume the repeated call of `replace` is quite inefficient but don't know how to do it better.

Answer (score 3):

I can believe it when the replace is the problem... it's creating a mess of nested code that's creating a lot of intermediate string values.

There's not much I can see to improve, though. The nesting can be reduced by combining a few of replaces...:

```
replace(.... , '\n|&#xA', '\\n')
```

Doing the same for `\t` and `\r` will reduce six calls to just three.

Additionally, I would consider wrapping the entire replace function in a `matches` call, that matches any of the patterns you are searching for, so you only need to do the full replacement call stack on values that actually require it. A large matches for all replaced values will, depending on how often values are actually required to be replaced, save time.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try this when I have to access to my computer again. Do you think I could rewrite this into even less replace calls when using something similar to the declaration of this method: http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/functx_escape-for-regex.html

Comment: I have worked with [Micahael Kay](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/31476/michael-kay) in the past on JDOM/Saxon integration, and he's very friendly, knowledgable and active on Stack Overflow too. I would recommend you rephrase your question in terms of a "this code is my attempt at replacing search items in the document as part of the transformation and it sucks! What alternatives are there that I should consider?", and tag it with the saxon tag. I am pretty certain that he reads all saxon questions (and JDOM questions too).

Comment: I tried your first suggestion and converted the 6 replaces into 3 which make use of the regex. The strange / sad thing is that when comparing 10 transformations of the original and the modified xslt the times are worse or equal.

Comment: @Marged - can we chat in [The 2nd monitor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor)

Comment: As suggested by you I created a new question on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31549633/how-do-i-use-saxon-to-do-multiple-search-replace-on-values-in-a-way-thats-effi